# Why this measure is not a Lebesgue measure on the power set of R?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In a video introducing measure theory, the Youtuber said that the Lebesgue measure on the power set of $\mathbb R$ does not exist
[image]. I wonder why the measure
$\mu = \sup {A}- \inf {A}, A \in P(\mathbb R)$ is not qualified?

The link of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur3ofJ61bpk&t=851s

Comment: What is your definition of $\mu (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: (1) and (2) are not the only required properties.  Also required: "measure".

Answer (score 1):

The function $\mu$ you are describing is not additive over disjoint sets: it gives $\mu(\{1,4\}) = 3$, $\mu(\{2,3\}) = 1$, but $\mu(\{1,2,3,4\}) = 3 \ne 3 + 1$. So it is not a measure.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: It also gives $\mu(\emptyset)=-\infty$.